# Access all column values of joined tables with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

Imagine one has two SQL tables

```
objects_stock
id | number
```

and

```
objects_prop
id | obj_id | color | weight
```

that should be joined on `objects_stock.id=objects_prop.obj_id`, hence the plain SQL-query reads

```
select * from objects_prop join objects_stock on objects_stock.id = objects_prop.obj_id;
```

How can this query be performed with SqlAlchemy such that all returned columns of this join are accessible?
When I execute

```
query = session.query(ObjectsStock).join(ObjectsProp, ObjectsStock.id == ObjectsProp.obj_id)
results = query.all()
```

with `ObjectsStock` and `ObjectsProp` the appropriate mapped classes, the list `results` contains objects of type `ObjectsStock` - why is that? What would be the correct SqlAlchemy-query to get access to all fields corresponding to the columns of both tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case someone encounters a similar problem: the best way I have found so far is listing the columns to fetch explicitly,

```
query = session.query(ObjectsStock.id, ObjectsStock.number, ObjectsProp.color, ObjectsProp.weight).\
   select_from(ObjectsStock).join(ObjectsProp, ObjectsStock.id == ObjectsProp.obj_id)
results = query.all()
```

Then one can iterate over the results and access the properties by their original column names, e.g.

```
for r in results:
    print(r.id, r.color, r.number)
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way of achieving the result of @ctenar's answer is by unpacking the columns using the star operator:

```
query = (
    session
    .query(*ObjectsStock.__table__.columns, *ObjectsProp.__table__.columns)
    .select_from(ObjectsStock)
    .join(ObjectsProp, ObjectsStock.id == ObjectsProp.obj_id)
)
results = query.all()
```

This is useful if your tables have many columns.